# Django Rest-Framework querying database

Tags: python, django, routes, django-rest-framework

I've got 2 models:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEMESTER)
    lecturer = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Lecture(models.Model):
    lecture_no = models.IntegerField(max_length=128, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And two viewsets:

```
class CourseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

class LectureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lecture.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LectureSerializer
```

And I'm trying to make it so that when you click on a course link, it only returns lectures given in that course. I can do this from the front end by filtering after returning all the lectures, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to query the database in Django. Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can filter `lectures` based on course by overring the `get_queryset` method in `LectureViewSet` like:

```
class LectureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LectureSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        course_id = self.request.query_params.get('course',False)
        if course_id:
            lectures = Lecture.objects.filter(course=course_id)
        else:
            lectures = Lecture.objects.all()
        return lectures
```

Now in your request you need to pass the course id in the URL when a course is clicked like:

```
.../api/lectures?course=1
```

the above request would return all the lectures with course id 1

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Doesn't this mean I need to add a URL for all courses then? Isn't there a way to do this with one url only?

Comment: @tryingtolearn no there will be only one url `.../api/lectures`, you need to append `?course=1` or `?course=2`. . . to the url based on the course clicked.

Comment: fantastic this does work. However, this works by the course object id right? Is there any way for me to access that information from the webapp end? How do I store that information in the model object?

Comment: @tryingtolearn yes this works by the course object id. when you call `.../api/courses` this should return all courses with its id's. You can use that id when a course is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using [django-filters.](https://github.com/alex/django-filter)

Here is what [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) has to say about it: [filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).